# Duplicate circles in D3

Tags: d3.js

I use D3.js and react. I added the drag and drop function from the examples, but when I start moving the circle, the display is duplicated. Instead of 6 'g', 12 appears. I can't figure out how to fix it in any way?

[image]

```
    const dragInteraction = d3.drag().on('drag', (event, node) => {
      node.fx = event.x;
      node.fy = event.y;
      simulation.alpha(1);
      simulation.restart();
      });

    const nodeElements = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr('fill', getNodeColor)
    .call(dragInteraction)
    const textElements = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('text')
    .text(node => node.label)
    .attr('font-size', 15)
    .attr('dx', 15)
    .attr('dy', 4)
    const linkElements = svg.append('g')
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(links)
      .enter().append('line')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('stroke', '#E5E5E5');


    simulation.nodes(nodes).on("tick", () => {
      nodeElements
        .attr("cx", node => node.x)
        .attr("cy", node => node.y)
      textElements
        .attr("x", node => node.x)
        .attr("y", node => node.y)
      linkElements
        .attr('x1', link => link.source.x)
        .attr('y1', link => link.source.y)
        .attr('x2', link => link.target.x)
        .attr('y2', link => link.target.y)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `circle` with `text` when appending `textElements`:

```
const textElements = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('text') // Replace circle with text here
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('text')
    ...
```